# How to enable ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Tags: raspbian

I'm beginner of raspberry pi and currently I'm installing ROS packages but further I proceed all the commands.

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

The upper commands shows the error : `unable to install ros-kinetic-desktop`.

Comment: Please provide some more information. If there is more information in the error given, please add it! Maybe [this link](https://answers.ros.org/question/243920/how-to-install-ros-kinetic-ubuntu-1604/) can help you out?

Comment: $ sudo sh -c ' echo "deb  http://packages .ros.org/ros/ubuntu  $( lsb_release -sc ) main" >  /  etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116  $ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo install ros-kinetic-desktop-full        from  last command it shows a error : unable to locate ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Answer (score 2):

> `sudo install ros-kinetic-desktop-full`

Although there is an `install` command, it is unrelated to what you want to do (if you want a clue as to what it is for, see `man install`).

What you should have done is:

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

Note the `apt`; `install` is a subcommand thereof just like `update` (`apt` and `apt-get` are more or less synonymous in this case; the former is a newer interface than `apt-get`).